# External Authentication in MVC 5 is username returned unique

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, google-oauth, facebook-oauth, owin

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 and using external authentication (Google and Facebook), after the user successfully returns when I call the GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() method I get a default username.

I cannot store this default returned username because this is not unique (even within Google or Facebook, I say that because for me it returns my name instead of my gmail id)

In MVC 4 it used to fetch the e-mail id but in MVC 5 it does not.

```
1. So my question is how can I get a unique name and store that as username?
```

The MVC 5 sample application asks user to choose a username, I don't want to do that I just want to grab users e-mail (or any unique id within a given provider realm) and use that as username.

```
2. How can this be safeguarded when user chooses to not give access 
   to e-mail/basic profile info when prompted?
```

Comment: In case of FB I get the users fbid (a string of digits) which I can prefix with "facebook-' and store as a username and it will be unique. Similarly for Google and Microsoft login am I guaranteed to get at least a unique username within Google/MS realm? 

My idea is to store username with prefixes like 'google-', 'MS-', 'facebook-' etc

Answer (score 0):

Simply look for the email claim and use that to create the local account.